# File/directory synchronization algorithms

Tags: java, synchronization, filesystemwatcher, directory-structure

I'm wondering about writing an application in Java which can synchronize files across my devices automatically (desktop, notebook, smartphone). Similar to Dropbox, however without a 3rd party server because i own my own.

Searching through the net i haven't found any helpful topics talking about synchronization algorithms which are used in such programs. I guess it's not an easy subject considering the fact that this problem is similar to revision control. Because of that i thinking about relaxing it. Eg. i don't (yet) want to implement optimization in data transfer for in-file changes so it's okay for me to transfer the whole file if it changed. Also it's fine for me if the system ask me for resolving conflicts manually between different file versions.

My biggest problem is the network communication. How should a slave client ask/tell my central storage server about file changes? I guess it's not a good idea to periodically transfer the whole file list with metadata to the server. As far as i see Dropbox checks the whole shared folder on startup then somehow notices changes on the local filesystem (i know there's a way to listen to file system change events in the OS, eg. Java7 has the `WatchService` class for this) and also listen to network sync events. Should i maintain file revisions like version control systems doing it or is there other solutions?

Are there any books or online materials about this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is rsync.  There *was* a Java implementation.. it might work but its not longer developed:  [JarSync](http://jarsync.sourceforge.net/)

The rsync algorithm transfers delta's of files so you don't incur the bandwidth hit of transferring the entire file.  If you are on linux, it might be easier to execute the native rsync client from the command line.

The WatchService is a nice utility to use to monitor for changes.  I believe it hooks into the operating systems native file change events rather than some naive polling mechanism that had to be used in years past.

If you want versioning support perhaps you should look into something like SVN?  [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) is probably the best java svn client.  I am not sure if SVN will transfer deltas.  (I doubt it).  Maybe you could look into using Git instead.  I know it transfers deltas.  Here is an eclipse project [Git client](http://eclipse.org/jgit/).

Good luck!

Comment: Given that SVN _stores_ deltas, I would imagine that it transfers them as well.

Comment: Well i'm working with SVN a lot so maybe it would be the best choice. But i fear it's a bit overkill for me to understand SVN's internal mechanics. I'll give it a try.I didn't know that SVNKit is a pure Java implementation of SVN, i thought it's just a wrapper around native binaries.

rsync is not an option on eg. Android. Also it's written in C and i'm not so fluent in C to understand every bit nicely.

Comment: @X-Zero, you are right.  It does transfer deltas according to the SVN Book.  I wasn't sure because it seems so much slower than Git :-P.

Comment: @Nagyl, Yes, SVNKit is pure Java.  I am sure you could get it to work for you.  You probably don't want to do full checkouts on android.  You might want to stick with remote repo browsing and use a lot of caching.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you only need to maintain a timestamp for each file. If that changes, you upload the file (or check the hash to see if has been changed before you upload)

If your project doesn't require pure Java, you could also consider leveraging `rsync` to do this.

Comment: The biggest problem with rsync is that it'll probably not run on a phone (say Android). Comparing timestamps is a minimalistic approach -  i've also thought about it.